# Is it possible to use JsonConverter to deserialize an object from a querystring?

Tags: asp.net, json, webforms, json.net

I have seen JsonConverter used to deserialize an object from JSON string. Is it possible to deserilize an object from query string? Or, bind query string values to object properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to build a JSON string from the querystring and then use JsonConverter to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you cannot do this. The methods ReadJSON() will only call if it sees that Request is POST and 
RequestBody contains a stringified string.